# Compute all solutions of $(2-z)^6 = z^6$ in the form$ z= x + iy$, $x,y$ are real numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

Compute all solutions of $(2-z)^6 = z^6$ in the form $z= x + iy$, x,y are real numbers

Hint: use that $(2-z)/z = 1^{1/6}$

Comment: Have you already solved it? If not how did you approach the problem?

Comment: I haven't yet solved it. I tried using the hint and an argand diagram of roots of unity but kept going round in circles!

Comment: Done it, thanks for the encouragement :)

Answer (score 1):

Follow your hint, we have 
$$ \left(\frac{2-z}z\right)^6 = 1 \iff (z-2)^6 = z^6 $$
so if $\zeta$ is a sixth root of one, we have
$$ \frac{2-z}z = \zeta \iff 2-z = \zeta z \iff z = \frac{2}{\zeta + 1} $$
Now use 
$$ z = \frac 2{\zeta + 1} = \frac{2(\bar \zeta + 1)}{\left|\zeta + 1\right|^2}
$$
Now use that the denominator is real, plug in all sixth roots of one and compute the corresponding values of $z$.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without the hint, using the complete $\mathbb Z$-factorization of $S^6-T^6$ as $(S-T)(S+T)(S^2+ST+T^2)(S^2-ST+T^2)$